# Screen bug after startup - BigSur 11.1

Tags: screen, login, bug

This issue is only happening at startup (right after I put the password); it does not happen if the Mac was sleeping.

**My hardware/software:** MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) running macOS Big Sur 11.1

**My issue:** After the first login, the screen shows - for half a second - colors strip much like you would get with a malfunctioning screen, it looks little bit like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shutterstock.com%2Fpt%2Fvideo%2Fclip-5445203-tv-color-bars-snow-noise&psig=AOvVaw0o-23NIHDD1sogQm5rLQEw&ust=1612657790714000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPCd0cmA1O4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD), but static and more random. Everything works just fine. It doesn't seen to be a major problem, more like a bug (never had this when it was running Catalina).

Anyone has had this same problem? It doesn't effect performance or anything as it just happen for a brief moment after login, but I mean, it wasn't supposed to happen.

Comment: In this case, I suggest you try resetting NVRAM following the instructions at this [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) site. Startup screen resolution settings are in NVRAM, and a reset may clear out a corrupt configuration and set it to default. Remember to go to System Preferences and set a screen resolution.

Comment: I also encounter this issue (somewhat randomly) during waking up from sleep. It has been going on for a year (or more), and during which I changed by screen. So it's probably related to GPU or system driver. It doesn't result in any errors so I just ignored it. I'm using MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) with High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G14042).